# How to set foreground and background colors on a WPF Menu control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu, menuitem, styling

I've been working in WPF for quite a while, but there's something basic about styling that I just don't get.

How can I set the foreground and background colors for a `Menu` control? I started with this:

```
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Background="#FF3A3A3A" Foreground="White">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit">
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

The foreground color is apparently inherited by the `MenuItem`, but the background is not. Next attempt:

```
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Background="#FF3A3A3A" Foreground="White">
        <MenuItem Background="#FF3A3A3A" Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit">
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

Now the highlight/overlay colors aren't right when the menu is activated, and I don't see an obvious property to set them. In addition, the menu popup has a wide, white border, and I don't see how to change it's color (or size), either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You will want to learn more about templates and styles in WPF (XAML really). In XAML, how a control looks and how a control operates are two completely different things. In your example, you may have a Foreground and Background property, but the style\template of the control my not utilize these properties for the display of the control.

Read http://wpftutorial.net/Templates.html and http://wpftutorial.net/TemplatesStyles.html, they will give you a good and quick overview. For a more in depth look, read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084.aspx

If you are using Visual Studio 2012 to edit your WPF UI, you can easily create a copy of the style\template the menu control is using, and then edit it. If you are using Visual Studio 2010, you should download and install (it may or may not be free) Expression Blend to edit your XAML UI.

> **Tip**: If you are using Visual Studio 2012, make sure your *Document Outline* window pane is visible all the time. This is very handy for editing a XAML UI. Mine defaulted to being collapsed on the left side of the program. This pane is visible in Expression Blend by default.

Find the MenuItem control in the Document Outline. Right-click on it and select Edit Template->Edit a Copy...

This will create a copy of the existing look-and-feel of the menu item for you to edit. When you do this, you will be in editing mode of that template, to "pop out" of that mode, click on the little icon on the top left of the Document Outline window.

[image: Return Scope Button]

When editing the template, you can see the layout and design of the template. When a menu item is being as the drop-down part, it's really displayed like a Popup menu (right click menu). Looking through that template, what pops out at me right away is this color resource named SubMenuBackgroundBrush:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SubMenuBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF5F5F5"/>
```

If you do a search for SubMenuBackgroundBrush you can see that it is used on a part named PART_Popup:

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="1" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" VerticalOffset="-1">
    <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
        <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FF959595" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource SubMenuBackgroundBrush}">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Margin="1,0" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{StaticResource SubMenuBackgroundBrush}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                    </Canvas>
                    <Rectangle Fill="#F1F1F1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,2" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Width="28"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="#E2E3E3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
</Popup>
```

This is the popup that you see when you right-click on something that shows a menu, or a dropdown menu. Change the references from: `{StaticResource SubMenuBackgroundBrush}` to `{TemplateBinding Foreground}`.

When you run the program, you'll see that the main background of the popup has changed, but the area where the icon is displayed has not. These are all the `<Rectangle Fill="` items in the popup control too. Change those also. The last reference to Rectangle looks like its the line splitting the icon and the text, you may not what to change that.

Enjoy the wonderful world of templates. It looks confusing and like a lot of work. It is. But when you get the hang of it, it's a **very cool** system. It's hard to go back to any other UI system after you get the hang of it.

Comment: Now I remember why I've avoided templates. Wow, what an ugly, totally unmaintainable mess to do something that should be so simple (the code in the answer above is different from and only a small fraction of the total that gets injected with Edit Template for the MenuItem). It's back to the default colors for me!

Comment: It only looks that way. It's really not. It's like the first time you opened up a large programming project. You were overwhelmed at all of the folders and files, you didn't know what to do. As you use templates and styles more, and you will, it's integral to XAML, it won't look like that anymore. For example, I've never looked at MenuItem before, and I didn't use any docs, but I was able to find the tweak very fast. One thing that helps is to store that style in your application.xaml, NOT the current parent control xaml.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your answer was what I was looking for. Maybe I'm using some non-default setting, but in my case, the template for MenuItem is 313 lines long! With colors spread throughout, in many places. Even in App.xaml, that's a lot of code to understand and maintain.

Comment: I know it is. :) Really the fact that the popup menu doesn't theme according to the parent menu seems like an oversight from the control designer. Other controls are a lot bigger than that. When you're editing the menu item, you're editing every style of view. So that is why its bigger than the simple "display text with color" declarations. The other thing that it is doing is setting properties for behavior, and hooking up events with the style (fade out fade in etc)

Comment: Depending on how the control is put together, you may have been able to just override a set property in the style. For example I noted that SubMenuBackgroundBrush resource the template was declared. If they were using that everywhere, you could have done a style override instead of a template override and just declared that resource with a new brush, very few lines. But they hardcoded some colors, so you couldn't.

Comment: C'est ce que je voulais depuis longtemps ! Merci beaucoup !

Comment: Agreed, its too much code to change a few colors here and there - not justified.

Answer (score 4):

> What am I missing?

Controls are more or less customizable, and there are two levels of customizing a control:

1. Setting properties like `Foreground`, `Background`, etc, in the XAML where you place the control.
2. Setting the `Template` in your `Style` for the control, and creating your own `ControlTemplate`.

The second is more involved, but it offers much more flexibility in making the control look how you want.  If this case, it sounds like that's what you'll need.  Check out the [default ControlTemplate for Menu and MenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296.aspx).  You can copy/paste them and modify as needed.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
                <!-- your modified template here -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <!-- your modified template here -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```