# Change the header/content in class system.windows.controls.menuitem?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a c#, WPF application with the notification in taskbar. And the design like this:

[image]

I want the app could tell the notification icon is clicked. For example, if you clicked on the **Change status**, it will be like this:

[image]

The code in main window design is like this:

```
<ContextMenu>
   <MenuItem 
      Header="LeftClicked" 
      Click="NodifierClick"/>
   <Separator/>
   <MenuItem Header="Reset" Click="NotifyIconClickReset" />
   <MenuItem Header="Show" Click="NotifyIconClickShow" />
   <MenuItem Header="Hide" Click="NotifyIconClickHide" />
   <MenuItem Header="Close" Click="NotifyIconClickClose" />
   <Separator/>
   <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="NotifyIconClickExit" />
</ContextMenu>
```

I have no idea that how to change the Header in the class System.Windows.Control.MenuItem, somebody has the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the quick and dirty way:

```
private void NotifyIconClickReset(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MenuItem)sender).Header = "LeftClicked";
}
```

But if you want to have a consistent reference to the menu item and make sure nothing else has its header changed by accident, you could give the item a name and reference it instead:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="_resetMenu" Header="Reset" Click="NotifyIconClickReset" />

private void NotifyIconClickReset(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _resetMenu.Header = "LeftClicked";
}
```

Comment: Could you not downcast the 'sender' argument to MenuItem and avoid having to name the MenuItems?

Comment: @AndrewArnold Thanks a lot, by the way, do you know how to change the color from black to grey too?

Comment: Depends what you want to do. You can disable it with `((MenuItem)sender).IsEnabled = false`, and that will grey it out, but if you want to just change the color things get a little trickier. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13783977/436282).