# WPF - Change menuitem background on mousehover and click

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I just create a menu in my WPF application. Here is the code

```
<Menu Background="#999" IsMainMenu="True" Grid.Row="1" >
    <MenuItem Padding="15, 3" Margin="5, 7" Height="26" Foreground="White" Header="_File"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Padding="15, 3" Margin="5, 7" Height="26" Foreground="White" Header="_Tools"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Padding="15, 3" Margin="5, 7" Height="26" Foreground="White" Header="_Control Options"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Padding="15, 3" Margin="5, 7" Height="26" Foreground="White" Header="_Settings"></MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

The only problem is when I hover or click any item, I am seeing a blue background in my menuitem. Can anyone tell me how can I change the background and border color? I am new in wpf.

**Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UUyj.png**

Comment: I have tried the above code and i see no Blue background. Please go through your XAML code and check if you are setting any style for MenuItms.

Comment: No I didn't. I am using windows 8. What is your os ? Actually it doesn't matter if the Blue background exists or not. I just want to set a custom background.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783705/how-to-set-foreground-and-background-colors-on-a-wpf-menu-control

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is because you are using the default template for the menu item. [MSDN: Styling  and Templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is an overview of the building blocks of controls in wpf, and how to customize behavior and style to each particular part of a control.

Right click your control, hover over edit template and click create a copy. You can then use this to make whatever changes you deem fit. There are event setters that set the background color when hovered ( just to point you in the direction of your issue )