# Center the content of the MenuItem in the Menu Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu, menuitem

I have a pretty stupid problem I'm not able to solve.
For my project I use WPF (and MVVM) and want a nice looking vertically aligned `Menu` control.
But I'm not able to center the content of my `MenuItems`.

Here is the XAML code of my menu:

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}" 
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CommandsTemplate}" 
      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CommandsStyle}">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
</Menu>
```

Here are my template and my style:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CommandsTemplate">
    <StackPanel Margin="4">
        <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="CommandsStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
</Style>
```

I tried setting `HorizontalAlignment` of the `StackPanel` to `Center`, `HorizontalContentAlignment`of my `Menu` to `Center`, etc. Nothing seems to work. If I set the background color of my `StackPanel` I see that it's just big enough to wrap my image and text. If I hover over an item, it's the full width of the menu. Online I wasn't able to find something that works in my case.

**EDIT**

Here is an example:

[image]

I want the whole thing to be in the center of the menu, not the text next to the icon!

**EDIT 2**

I tested some things and came close to what I wanted. I added this to my `CommandsStyle`:

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
```

Sadly, it made hovering over the button pretty ugly.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

So it's still not exactly what I want.

**ANSWER**

I was nearly giving up and tried to work on other design things of my `MenuItem`. One of them was changing the hover color of it. And I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888636/change-background-color-of-menuitem-on-mouseover) post. Then I added `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` to my `StackPanel` and now it works!

Here is the updated code:

```
<Style x:Key="CommandsStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd"  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                        Uid="Border_38">
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4">
                        <Image Width="32" Source="{Binding IconSource}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="LightGray"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is how it looks when I hover over my `MenuItem`:

[image]

Comment: Change your StackPanel to Grid and add columns for text and Image. column width should be `*` for text and `Auto` for Image, then make the `TextBlock` horizontal alignment to `Center`.

Comment: Hey, I see that problem may be stack panel.  Could you please test with that parameters : <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">.  If that doesnt work, I think you need nested stack panels

Comment: I tried it with those parameters but it still doesn't work. Could you show me an example of how you would use nested stack panels?

Comment: Since we don't see the all XAML code, it is really hard to say what would cause that problem. Have you checked Margin of "Menu".

Comment: I was about to answer when I saw you already resolved the issue! :) Look for me in Twitter (I have the same username).