# C# Wpf : how do i set a background color of items in an menu item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to set the background color of the menu items in a menu item like this:

[image: This]

I have a **style** for my context menu but it apparently doesn't change the colors for that.

I've tried changing the menu items background but that doesn't change the borders background it looks like this:

[image: this]

I've tried creating a **style** that changes the border but it makes the whole thing like this:

[image: This]

Style of my context menu :

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}" x:Key="conte">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Secendery}" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" BorderThickness="0.5" CornerRadius="5">
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle">
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Style I've tried to put as itemcontainerstyle:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="conteItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Secendery}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,5,5,5" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Secendery}" CornerRadius="5" Background="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}">
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle">
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close with your `MenuItem` style, but you need to specify the correct parts of that template. In particular, the `<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" ...>` tag specifies the pop-up menu that you get when you click on a `MenuItem` to see its child. But, you also need to include the other portions that you want to display such as `x:Name="Icon"`, `x:Name="content"`, etc...

This example below borrows heavily from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51149174/15534202), and it was able to achieve what I think you are looking for

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Cyan" BorderThickness="1">

                        <DockPanel>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="4,0,6,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="7,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="1" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" VerticalOffset="-1">

                        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="true" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="LightCyan" TargetName="content" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```