# WPF- How to Make Menu control look native

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am currently learning WPF framework; I have some past (not much though) experience with Winforms. One problem I've had in both is that the menubar does not look native. I've found a workaround in Winforms, but I haven't been able to find anything for WPF. I've not had this problem in other frameworks I've used, particularly Qt.

In many pics I've seen, it looks native enough in Windows 7, but not Windows 10. I included some pics.

How it currently looks:
[image]

How it should look:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
While I have not seen the possible duplicate link, I am aware of setting the foreground/background on WPF controls. That link doesn't really answer my question. I don't want to come up with my own style at this point; all I want to do is make controls look native.

If custom styling is the only way, that's fine, but if there is another way, that would be preferable.

Thanks!

Comment: Whats the difference? Shortcuts and icons?

Comment: In the first pic, the menubar is grey, and the menu doesn't look native. Every other application on Windows has a white, more smooth menubar, like the second pic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set foreground and background colors on a WPF Menu control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783705/how-to-set-foreground-and-background-colors-on-a-wpf-menu-control)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a quick fix to get what you want. WPF renders using DirectX, allowing for much more flexibility in styling applications. A WPF app should render exactly the same way on any version of Windows - it will not automatically adopt a native look and feel (that was actually one of the main selling points of the technology in its early days).

While MS made the default styling somewhat close to Windows at the time of release (Vista, I think?), if you want WPF controls to have a particular look you're going to have to style them yourself.

Comment: I was kind of afraid of that, but that makes sense. Thanks for a good explanation though; I haven't that yet.